# Is using std::vector< std::shared_ptr<const T> > an antipattern?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std

For a long time I was using `std::vector` and `std::shared_ptr` hand in hand. Recently I started using `std::shared_ptr<const T>` whenever a pointer to a const object was needed. This is all OK, since `std::shared_ptr<T>` can be cast to `std::shared_ptr<const T>` and then they share the same reference counter and everything feels natural.

But when I try to use constructs such as `std::vector< std::shared_ptr<const T> >` I run into troubles. To simplify I will denote the two structures:

```
template <class T>
using SharedPtrVector = std::vector< std::shared_ptr<T> >;

template <class T>
using SharedConstPtrVector = std::vector< std::shared_ptr<const T> >;
```

The problem is that although `SharedPtrVector` and `SharedConstPtrVector` are very similar, `SharedConstPtrVector` cannot be cast to `SharedPtrVector`.

So each time I want to be a const correct and write a function such as:

```
void f(const SharedConstPtrVector<T>& vec);
```

there is no way I can pass const `SharedPtrVector<T>` to `f`.

I was thinking about this a lot and considered several alternatives:

1. Write conversion functions

   ```
   template <typename T>
   SharedConstPtrVector<T> toConst(const SharedPtrVector<T>&);
   ```
2. Write code in generic form:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   void f(const std::vector< std::shared_ptr<T> >& vec);
   ```

   or

   ```
   template <typename TIterator>
   void f(TIterator begin, TIterator end);
   ```
3. Abandon the idea of `std::vector< std::shared_ptr<const T> >`

The problem with 1. is the computational overhead and increased uglyness of code, while 2. gives the code an "everything is a template" flavor.

I am an inexperienced programmer and I don't want to set out in the wrong direction. I would like to hear advice from someone who has experience with this problem.

Comment: TL;DR; Depends on the use case, as always with patterns/antipatterns => [golden hammer](http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/golden-hammer)

Comment: I think your problem is rather passing a container when you don't need to modify it. That's what ranges (and iterator pairs) are there for. You don't need to use templates either, you can use pointers as well here as iterators. OTOH, if `f` is an algorithm, make it a template to make it generic => reusable (as a mathematician, you might like Alexander Stepanov's approach).

Comment: @dyp `you can use pointers as well here as iterators` and then pass the vector using the `std::vector::data` member function? Or how do you mean it?

Comment: I wouldn't abandon the idea at all. Going to range-based algorithms via iterators *mostly* makes sense. It does have the drawback of not providing a means of performing *container* manipulation (adding/removing elements), however, which is something you *can* do with your attempted approach if the container reference is non-const. If the reference is const, I see no reason *not* to use a range-based alternative.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Exactly, `vec.data()` and `vec.data() + vec.size()`

Comment: *"For a long time I was using `std::vector` and `std::shared_ptr` hand in hand."* already sounds like you're misusing both of them. `shared_ptr` should not be a common occurrence.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would suggest reviewing your design with a view to establish a clear owner of those object. This is the absence of clear ownership that lead people to use shared smart pointers.

Bjarne Stroustrup recommends using smart pointers only as a last resort. His recommendations (best to worst) are:

1. Store an object by value.
2. Store many objects in a container by value.
3. If nothing else works, use smart pointers.

See [Bjarne Stroustrup - The Essence of C++: With Examples in C++84, C++98, C++11, and C++14](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative/2013/Opening-Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup) at 0:37:40.

Comment: I use `shared_ptr` for data which is accessed by several GUI windows which are running in parallel. I think this is a good use case, but maybe this was premature optimization on my side. I will try the "by value" approach.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Presumably, something (an object) in your application owns those windows. That something could also own those objects shared by those windows. There is often a hierarchy of objects in application, if it is hiding make an effort to uncover it.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik You might try MVCing it so that the windows that need access register as Observers with another class that owns the state.  That way you get cleanly identifiable ownership with rules for access.

Comment: I'm using this very thing for creating a pool of buffers in a transparent proxy. Sessions claim a recycled buffer (or a new one if none available) and then recycle them when the session completes. There's absolutely no need to give a rip about who is clearly the owner of those objects because they're loose as a goose, get passed around the camp. So I think the answer should at least hint that it's not infallible divine decree and can be acceptable in the right situation.

Comment: Also we need to remember that no matter how brilliant people are, they're still fallible human beings and capable of having a wrong opinion. Bjarne is a cool guy but not everything he says is right. I've also heard him claim that the vast majority of people who use C++ are using it wrong. So if we're altering how we think and work unquestioningly by his advice, we should probably just uninstall our compilers and go home. :)

Comment: @TechnikEmpire Man up, go big or go home.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Your comment doesn't seem make any sense. Man up about what?

Answer (score 8):

**1** The problem is not related to `shared_ptr<>`, but occurs already for ordinary pointers:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(std::vector<const T*>);

int a,b;
std::vector<int*> bar={&a,&b};
foo<???>(bar);        // no value for ??? works
```

**2** The construct `vector<shared_ptr<T>>` is sensibly only iff there is no owner to the objects hold.

Comment: You can even boil this down to `int const**` vs `int**`. The latter is not convertible to the former.

Answer (score 2):

It is a valid way of storing immutable (and thus thread safe) objects, a building block for a per-element copy-on-write cache. Definitely not an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

if you insist on keeping `std::vector` you can try to encapsulate it into a handle-body idiom structure.

this allows you to keep a non `const` shared pointer in a `const` handle.

Answer (score 0):

If I am storing thousands of 3d points (e.g. in a std::vector) and want to push the address of those entries into another structure (say a heap for sorting or other purposes) and the secondary structure might need to delete some of those entries (e.g. values closer than the stated accuracy of the sensor), who is the 'owner'?  It seems like the best solution is a vector of smart pointers, exactly what Stroustrup suggests should be the last resort, with the points themselves allocated on the heap?